# Angular + Jasmine: beforeEach() syntax with module()

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

Can you please explain how this line works:

> beforeEach(module('phonecatApp'));

beforeEach() expects a callback function to call before each test.
module() returns an angular.Module object.

What does beforeEach() do with an object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look in the source of [`angular.mock.module`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.3.15/src/ngMock/angular-mocks.js#L2275) you can see it either returns a function, or the result of a function, depending on whether a spec is running:

```
window.module = angular.mock.module = function() {
  var moduleFns = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
  return isSpecRunning() ? workFn() : workFn;
  /////////////////////
  function workFn() {
    ...
```

When `beforeEach` is called, I suspect this is treated as *not* being during a spec, so the function returns a callback that runs when the test runner later calls the callbacks registered with `beforeEach`.

---

Also I don't see documented, or in the source, that it actually *returns* a module object. It apparently *registers* a module with the dependency injection system.

Comment: Thank you. I thought it was the same as angular.module(), so I was looking at that API, not ngMock. Not evident at first sight.